# How to create a search bar that fixes or prevents spelling mistakes?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, best-practice, search-terms

So my customers tend to be more so individuals who are not computer literate and often make errors when searching for our products. What is the best way to work out what they're trying to search for and serve it to them? Preferably for free. I'm not asking for module recommendations necessarily if there's code in Magento 2 that I can go in and edit to serve this purpose, that would be most ideal. What is the best way to get this functionality implemented in to my search bar?

EDIT: I'm gonna go with Piyush's replies in the comments, i'm not even allowed to use a third party extension I asked my boss. Instead i'm going to code it based on the github links Piyush left me in reply to this question.

Comment: May be you are looking for this [Autocomplete search](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-search-atocomplete-free.html)

Comment: Piyush you're wonderful and thank you but is it possible to do it through code rather than installing 3rd party extensions, my employer has set a limit on the amount of 3rd party plugins i'm allowed to use, speed concerns primarily, their last Magento site had so many plugins it caused them issues before I joined

Comment: Even if you want to do it by your own code  rather than purchasing third party extension, you have to create an extension. So it won't make any difference.

Comment: anyways if you want some reference code, you can check [this](https://github.com/pratikmage/magento2-catalog-search-autocomplete) and [this](https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch)

Comment: I don't mind writing my own extension, it's only a ban on 3rd party extensions, anything written by myself is fine

Comment: thank you for the code references I think i'm going to try use them to write my own, thank you again Piyush you're an absolute legend

Comment: @Piyush if you make your autocomplete search comment and then the github links comment in to one answer, i'll happily accept it

Comment: @Piyush you should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for [Auto Complete Search](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-search-atocomplete-free.html). If you are looking for reference code you can check below github Modules

1. [Link 1](https://github.com/pratikmage/magento2-catalog-search-autocomplete)
2. [Link 2](https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch)

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 it does provide this feature which is called "Search Synonyms"

See [this](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/search-synonyms.html) link to setup your search [`synonym`](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/search-synonyms.html).

It does facilitate you to add related words (which we can say alternative words or spelling mistake words).

**For eg:**

> you are selling **hoodie** while some customer calls it **hodie** or **sweatshirt** or **sweat shirt** so you can create a synonym group for this like: **sweatshirt, sweat shirt, hoodie, fleece, hodie**.

Comment: I have over 100,000 products, i cannot do that for every possible search term and/or product, i think i'm going with Piyush's reply to my question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should you give a try at ElasticSuite that handle spelling mistakes and phonetic search out-of-the-box among many other valuable features => https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite.

Disclosure : I am ElasticSuite architect and lead developper.